# SSL CA certificate in java

Tags: java, ssl

I have a question about the usage of ssl in java.

My need is quite simple, to connect to a server (https, ldaps, ...), using the CA certificate of the server (pem format)

When using api as curl or many other I guess, in C++ or command line, you can specify a single CA certificate (in pem format for instance) when performing a connection.

If I well searched (hum), in java (i mean with standard librararies) it's slightly different.

- either you add your certificate into a trustore, having to manage it by external application as keytool (of course you could programmatically manage your trustore, but it's not my point)
  [and additionally, you can specify a trustore with System property, but you can't specify a cert directly]
- either you have to code a little, like overloading the SslContext or the TrustManager class, to enable to add a certificate "on the fly".

Am I missing a simpler way, like method "connection.setCA(String caCertPath)" ?

Thank you,

Comment: "to connect to a server (https, ldaps, ...), using the CA certificate of the server" already doesn't make sense. The *server* uses its certificate, not you.

Comment: Well, i think that I (more precisely the client) use the CA certificate to validate the server certificates.

Comment: More precisely, the CA certificate *is* one of the server certificates. The client validates them all.

Comment: Yes I do agree, I just wanted to underline that the client needs to "have" the CA certificate by its side to be able to validate the server certificate. So it "uses" it in the way he has to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "Am I missing a simpler way, like method "connection.setCA(String caCertPath)" ?"

I guess it depends on the java class you use to implement the application.
But as far as my knowledge goes the answer is: no. You indeed need to first store the certificate in a keystore to be consumed by the class you are using.

I am not aware of any class that would work the way you expect the certificates to be consumed, but I guess you could just write that class to sit on top of the class you don't like.